# Why cannot I delete User from standard JDBC Repository - Spring Boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to delete an entity in User table, but when I call this method

```
companyRepository.deleteById(userID);
```

NOTHING happens. Absolutely nothing.

My entities are:

User:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    private long user_id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

Role:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Role {
    @Id
    private long role_id;

    private String role;

}
```

What I have tried with:

- Change the CascadeType.ALL to different cascade type, or cascade types.
- Change FetchType.EAGER to FetchType.LAZY

But when I don't include **CascadeType.PRESIST** or **FetchType.EAGER**, I cannot login. This is because these entities are standard configurations for JDBC JPA. So I need them.

**Question:**

- Why can I not delete my user?
- Do you know another setup of entities with role and user that might work for deleting?
- I cannot change an user because then Spring Boot complains that I trying to "overwrite" an entity with a same id-number, in this case, column index 0.
- I can add a new user, no problem.

**Edit:**

Update method:

```
@PostMapping("/updateuser")
    public HTTPMessage uppdateUser(@RequestBody User user, @RequestParam("updatepassword") boolean updatepassword) {
        // Check if user exist
        if (userRepository.findById(user.getUser_id()) != null) {

            // Check if our email/username is right
            boolean valid = EmailValidator.getInstance().isValid(user.getUsername());
            if(valid == false)
                return new HTTPMessage("Email: " + user.getUsername() + " is not valid", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE.value());

            // Update the password if we say that it should be updated
            if (updatepassword == true)
                user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

            // Count and user id
            long rows = userRepository.count();
            long userID = user.getUser_id();

            // Delete
            roleRepository.deleteById(userID);
            // Delete the user and the online
            userRepository.deleteById(userID);

            // Set new ID and save
            user.setUser_id(rows);
            for(Role role : user.getRoles())
                role.setRole_id(user.getUser_id());
            userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);


            // Update the compant table too
            rows = companyRepository.count();
            companyRepository.deleteById(userID);
            Company saveCompany = new Company();
            saveCompany.setId(rows);
            saveCompany.setUsername(user.getEmail().split("@")[0]);
            saveCompany.setCompany(user.getEmail().split("@")[1].split("\\.")[0]); // From "myUser@MyCompany.com" to "MyCompany"
            saveCompany.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            companyRepository.saveAndFlush(saveCompany);
            return new HTTPMessage("User: " + user.getUsername() + " is updated", HttpStatus.OK.value());

        } else {
            return new HTTPMessage("User: " + user.getUsername() + " does not exist", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        }
    }
```

User repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

}
```

Role repository

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Long> {

}
```

Company repository

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Long> {

    Company findByUsername(String username);
}
```

The result is that I can add new user, but not remove or override user.

Comment: What does  `repository` have `companyRepository` variable? please add it code as well.

Comment: Please paste interface companyRepository to question?

Comment: I undestand now that I did. I set the id to 0 to begin with. It should start with 1

Comment: So rows was 0, right? then was this fixed?

Comment: @JonathanJohx yes. Never set id to 0